# Harmonic function on a ring

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

$\Delta f = 0$ in $X$ where $X=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2:r_1 < |x| < r_2\}$.The boundary condition is $f(r_1,\phi)=v(\phi),f(r_2,\phi)=w(\phi)$.Solve a solution $f$.

My try:I used separation of variables and got a very long and complicated form.But I am curious if there is any other better methods like  M.V.P. or something else?

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand what you asked.Do you mean what is f in X?

Comment: Should it be $x\in\Bbb R$ or $x\in\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @ Xander Henderson @edm   Thank your for reminding me.I just edited the post.I think this would help now.